# I wonder if there is an easy way to set a little image inside Material styled TextField - without overriding the whole TextField control

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I wonder if there is an easy way to set a little image inside Material styled TextField - without overriding the whole TextField control. 
I'm trying to create a searchBox.

Comment: To my experience, the best way is to create a customized element. But it's hard to say without any part of code or image describing your actual purpose.

Comment: Just a material ui textField with magnified glass image on the left side. (like in stackoverflow search) that's all.

Comment: Check this page as well https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-material.html . The material theme allows you customizing at least five options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate `background` property of `TextField` element. Check out this example:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.12
import "qrc:/"

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Material.theme: Material.Dark
    TextField{
        width: 128
        height: 32
        rightPadding: 32
        background: Rectangle{
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 1
            Image {
                anchors{
                    right: parent.right
                    verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }
                width: 32
                height: 32
                source: "qrc:/zoom.png"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

This is the easiest way I know for this task without creating a custom element. The thing is - you got to do some additional customizations to make it look material again, cause background replaces other things.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create your own custom component and set whatever you need inside. In this case, create an Item (or Rectangle), anchor the text field at one side and anchor the icon to the other. It will work without any suprises. In general this is the best way to approach this kind of problems.